# What xmlAdapter use JAXB to unmarshlad base64Binary

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

when I use hexBinary in xsd schema JAXB use HexBinaryAdapter to convert it into byte.
But how JAXB convert when I use base64Binary in XSD schema ? there is no XmlAdapter. He use default xmlAdapter or what ? How it is converting ?
thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none, because `base64Binary` is the JAXB default for handling binary data.  You just annotate a `byte[]` field/property, and it's marshalled/unmarshalled automatically as `base64Binary`.

Comment: yea but there must be some conversion how JAXB make with string binary data

Comment: @hudi: Yes, but it's not exposed in the public API.